# PHP switch and if statement output different results

Tags: php, conditional-statements

Could someone please explain what's going on here?
Here's the code:

```
$num = 0;

switch($num){

case ($num==0):
    echo $num ,  " is ZERO";
    break;

case ($num>0):
    echo $num ,  " is POSITIVE";
    break;

default:echo $num , " is NEGATIVE";
}
```

The above outputs 0 is POSITIVE

```
if($num==0){

print ($num." is ZERO");

} 

elseif($num>0){

echo $num ,  " is POSITIVE";

}

else{

echo $num , " is NEGATIVE";

}
```

This works as expected - 0 is ZERO. 
If I replace
  case($num==0) with case(0) the output is OK.

Why does the case($num==0) fail?
Someone told me the issue with evaluating multiple expressions in the case statements, but it seems fine syntactically.

Comment: `switch` is __not__ simply an alternative syntax for `if` statements: you're matching the value of `$num` from the actual `switch ($num)` against the values of `($num==0)`, `($num>0)` which are actually two Booleans; so comparing a falsey 0 with a Boolean true or false (after typecasting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`switch` compares everything in the `switch (...)` expression to each case:

```
switch ($num) {
    case 0 :
        ...
    case 1 :
        ...
    ...
}
```

You don't write `case $num == 0`, as that's equivalent to `if ($num == 0 == $num)`.

If at all, you'd have to do:

```
switch (true) {
    case $num == 0 :
        ...
    case $num > 0 :
        ...
    ...
}
```

But there are people who frown upon that.

Answer (score 1):

The logical structure of switch operator is this:

```
switch($x):
case val1:
    action 1;
    break;

case val2:
    action 2;
    break;

default:
    not val1 and val2;
```

switch compares $x with one of the values or gives `default` branch in case nothing matches. So, you can't write:

```
case ($num > 0):
```

or

```
case ($num == 0 ):
```

In your case it gives POSITIVE, because php first evaluates the expressions inside cases, and we get the following in the output:

```
Is $num == 0 ?: yes => 1
Is $num > 0 ?: no => 0
```

And the real switch php evaluates is this:

```
$num = 0;

switch($num){

case 1:
    echo $num ,  " is ZERO";
    break;

case 0:
    echo $num ,  " is POSITIVE";
    break;

default:
    echo $num , " is NEGATIVE";
}
```

Output is: POSITIVE.